# How can I restore a folder in pantheon-files

Tags: pantheon-files

Unfortunately I deleted  the folder "Downloads" in pantheon-files (left side of window)

How can I restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer will work anytime (provided you have not emptied the Trash). If you realise your mistake immediately after doing it, you can also press Ctrl-Z to undo most actions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, go to Trash, right click the folder and Restore.